# Div Background Does Not Show

Tags: html, css

I have a strange problem.

Background that was set by CSS for `.article-container` and `<article>` does not displays at all (neither image nor color). Background that was set for `<article>` children displays property.

**The page:** http://new.elenaakulova.com.ua/.

Or **the code:**

```
<div id="article-container">
  <article id="about-me">
    <div id="photo">
      <img src="http://placehold.it/300x404" width="300px">
    </div>
    <div id="description">
      <hgroup>
        <h2>психолог</h2>
        <h1>Вася Пупкин</h1>
      </hgroup>
      <p>Здравствуйте!</p>
    </div>
  </article>
</div>
```

and

```
#article-container {
  width: 1000px;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  background: white;
}

#article-container > article {
  background: white;
}

#about-me #description {
  float: left;
  background: blue;
}
```

Comment: which browser? you are using some modern css syntax like `>`. that's not supported by some browsers.

Comment: try `background-color: #ffffff;` instead of `background: white;`.

Comment: which computed height has your tag `<article>`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add `overflow: hidden;` to `#article-container`

> Floats, absolutely positioned elements, inline-blocks, table-cells,
>   table-captions, and elements with 'overflow' other than 'visible'
>   (except when that value has been propagated to the viewport) establish
>   new block formatting contexts.
>        In a block formatting context, each box's left outer edge touches the left edge of the containing block (for right-to-left formatting,
>   right edges touch). This is true even in the presence of floats
>   (although a box's line boxes may shrink due to the floats), unless the
>   box establishes a new block formatting context (in which case the box
>   itself may become narrower due to the floats).

The block formatting context clears the floats. Source: http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visuren.html#block-formatting

Comment: Or auto, or scroll, or whatever is appropriate.

Answer (score 0):

The reason is that your `#photo` and `#description` are floated. So the parent looses its dimensions, because there is no content within the document flow.

Set `float:left;` for the `<article>`. That solves your problem.

Answer (score 0):

```
#article-container > article {
  background: white;
}
```

this is showing up white, it just has no height , sp it's not visible try,

```
#article-container > article {
  background: white;
  height:400px;
}
```